# How to maintain current zoom level when panning to a new feature?

Tags: arcmap, scale, zoom

I want to speed up my work. How could I get ArcMap to stay at my current zoom level when panning to a new feature?

What I am currently doing is using `Ctrl+Enter` to move through my attribute table and `Ctrl+=` to zoom to my point. However, ArcMap will not maintain my current zoom level and no amount of messing around in scale settings has kept it where I need it to be. Even if I have only the scales I want in the drop down it will still put me at 1:7534 anytime I zoom to a new point.

Comment: I am voting to close it because it is duplicate of previous question. -1 btw for no feedback on any of 3 solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try Ctrl N.  You want to pan to the selected feature.

See http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/keyboard-shortcuts-for-working-with-tables.htm

Answer (score 0):

[Data Driven Pages](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/map/page-layouts/creating-data-driven-pages.htm) is handy for this kind of task. You can use DDP tools in the data or layout views. Have a look at the [Center and maintain scale](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/map/page-layouts/creating-data-driven-pages.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_9F531CE4A9E24F2D900F87CE6A328876) option in particular. In your case, the layer you're using the attribute table to step through will become your *index layer*.

From the documentation:

> Data Driven Pages gives you the ability to generate a set of output
>   pages by taking a single layout and iterating over a set of map
>   extents. The extents are defined by the features in a layer and are
>   sometimes called tiles, sections, or areas of interest (AOI). The
>   layer that defines the extents is referred to as an index layer. Any
>   feature layer may serve as the index layer. You create and customize
>   new Data Driven Pages using the Setup Data Driven Pages dialog box.
>   This dialog box contains two tabs: Definition and Extent. You can
>   activate this dialog box from the Data Driven Pages toolbar or from
>   the Page and Print Setup dialog box.